# Ubuntu installation is giving an error

Tags: boot, laptop, samsung

I was installing Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop, during installation there was no problem but this problem occurred as soon as I clicked on "restart now". Can anyone help me, I tried to reinstall three times, but nothing has changed.

[image: error-message]

Comment: Please be specific with details; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has different products (Server, Desktop & *flavors*) which have different installers (`ubiquity`, `subiquity` plus *flavors*) and different kernel stacks (5.15 is GA, 5.19, 6.2 & now also 6.5 if using a *daily*) but you didn't specify which 22.04 you used (Server uses GA, Desktop uses HWE but it varies on 22.04, 22.04.2, 22.04.3 etc).  On installing you can use one kernel, then on first reboot a different kernel is actually used (if using an ISO that uses HWE, but you didn't specify product).. What Ubuntu 22.04 ISO are you trying to install/use